# How to get object in c#

Tags: c#

```
ObjetosAuxiliar.ReservaServicoResumo resumoServico = new ObjetosAuxiliar.ReservaServicoResumo();

resumoServico.Quantidade = this.ReservaServico.Sum(r => r.Quantidade);
resumoServico.ValorTotal = this.ReservaServico.Sum(r => r.Quantidade * r.Servico.Valor);
resumoServico.Servico = r.Servico; --WRONG

return resumoServico;
```

How to get in `resumoServico.Servico` the object `r.Servico`?

Comment: it looks like you can have multiple different values, which one you want to get?

Comment: Servico is a object and I need to get this object to be set in resumoServico.Servico
Is possible to access Servico in r.Servico but I don´t know another way to get this object

Comment: It looks like `ReservaServico` is a collection type, correct? If so, then it sounds like the type that it contains has the `Servico` property that you want. If that's correct, then you can get the first one with `ReservaServico.First().Servico;`. But it may contain objects that have different values for the `Servico` property. You haven't shown us enough of the types to give a valid answer.

Comment: If I use .First() only the first object will be seted. If i have multiple objects in ReservaServico (ICollection) will be seted with wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding something.

`r` is not a real object (per se), is a representation that you use for the `ReservaServico` in order to use the `Sum` method, `r` only exists inside the call for that method.

So, I think what you are looking for is:

```
resumoServico.Servico = this.ReservaServico.Servico;
```

**UPDATE**

If `ReservaServico` is a collection, the only way of get the values is to store them in a collection, if this is the case you can do it this way.

```
ObjetosAuxiliar.ReservaServicoResumo resumoServico = new ObjetosAuxiliar.ReservaServicoResumo();

resumoServico.Quantidade = this.ReservaServico.Sum(r => r.Quantidade);
resumoServico.ValorTotal = this.ReservaServico.Sum(r => r.Quantidade * r.Servico.Valor);

foreach(var r in ReservaServico)
{
    resumo.Servico.Add(r.Servico);
}
```

For this to work, `resumo.Servico` has to be a collection of `ReservaServico.Servico`, if you can't change the type you can't have the collection of `Servico`.

Comment: Servico is not accessible in ReservaServico.Servico beacuse ReservaServico is a ICollection

Comment: what is the type of `resumoServico.Servico`?

Comment: Servico is a object of type Servico that contains 4 properties

Comment: See the files.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aoDxtmOikkeMVRYBoyuVane_NMUT0Gdt
Open the file Reserva in the line 113

Comment: If you have relevant code to the question, please edit the question and add it, so other people can see it too.